# Скорость выполнения на jquery или js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, производительность

На чём быстрее будет скорость выполнения на чистом js или jquery в этом примере?

```
function callMeShow() {
    var form = document.getElementById("tsCallMeWrap");

    form.style.display = 'block';
    form.className = 'tsCallMeWrap-opening';

    form.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend", function() {
            form.className = null;
    });
}

function callMeShow()
{
    $('#tsCallMeWrap').show();

    $('#tsCallMeForm').addClass('tsCallMeWrap-opening');

    $('#tsCallMeForm').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
            $('#tsCallMeForm').removeClass('tsCallMeWrap-opening');
    });
}
```

Comment: функции делают разные действия, поэтому сравнивать не совсем корректно. В большинстве случае быстродействие js без jQuery выше, за счет отсутствия создания объектов самого jQuery, но при этом может падать скорость разработки

Comment: кроме того, похоже ошибка в использовании _addEventListener_

Comment: Функции делают одно и тоже (поправил названия классов для большей идентичности).
Показывают элемент. Добавляют к этому элементу класс (к нему привязана css-анимация), после выполнения анимации, убирают этот класс.

Comment: на самом деле не одно: `show` Не обязательно делает _display = 'block'_, `one` добавляет удаляет обработчик после первого срабатывания. Во второй функции ты ищешь элемент с id=tsCallMeWrap _каждый_ раз, когда тебе нужен элемент, а в первой, ты нашел форму один раз и потом ее используешь. _removeClass_ удаляет **конкретный** класс, _className = null_ - удаляет **все** классы. _addClass_ - добавляет конкретный класс, _className = 'tsCallMeWrap-opening'_ - **заменяет** все классы на указанный

Comment: В любом случае, на глаз заметить разницу в скорости выполнения обеих функций будет проблематично

Comment: В наши дни компьютеры достигли таких мощностей что даже приличные по весу библиотеки работают очень быстро. Не обращайте внимания на микросекунды

Comment: В одном проекте с аналитическим веб-приложением у меня были сотни элементов на странице, их надо было скрывать и отображать в нужные моменты. На этом `hide/show` из JQuery дико зависали, пришлось покопаться в его коде и написать свой быстрый аналог. Если у Вас ситуация не такая, то можете спокойно использовать JQuery `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Это делается легко.

```
var t1 = performance.now();
// Код, который хочешь замерить.
var t2 = performance.now();
var resultTime = t2 - t1;
console.log('Время выполнения скрипта: ', resultTime );
```

Но стоит, наверно, погуглить и почитать про <s>сектанские</s> теории о том, насколько много jquery может навешивать бессмысленных обработчиков на события, казалось бы, пустяковые. Об этом вам сказали в комментариях.